# Window and Decoration Style programming in KDE5 with QT

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt5, kde-plasma

I have been looking for information over the internet but haven´t been able to find specific information on the subject.

I see there are lots of information about theming, widgets and icons. I am starting to practice some programming using QT5 and I always wanted to play with the KDE GUI design.

What I am basically interested in is how do you programatically style the windows and decorations at a system wide level?

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly: you are looking for a way to write a Qt based program for changing the style of the GUI of the whole OS, is that so?

Comment: Yes, I wan to to style the KDE GUI which I know uses QT5, If I am not wrong that is done by kwin but the only official info I could find is scarse, from version 4 which in time points to a tutorial for KDE 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plasma's window manager `kwin` uses the [`libKDecoration2`](https://cgit.kde.org/kdecoration.git/) library to handle decorations. Check the `*.h` headers there for documentation.

Both [Breeze](https://cgit.kde.org/breeze.git/tree/kdecoration) and [Oxygen](https://cgit.kde.org/oxygen.git/tree/kdecoration) decoration use this library from C++.

You can find a smaller example decoration at http://skulpture.maxiom.de/playground/skeleton-0.1.tar.xz

Comment: Wonderful, exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Is that yours? really nice work man, I like it.